# Stylesheet not working on change on secure server https

Tags: html, css, ssl

Hi i have a website that was previously running on http and now on secure server https. When it was running on http, change in style sheet was effecting web page immediately. But now when i used secure server https, changes in style sheet are not being effected. I have used cloudflare SSL certificate.

I have tried on Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome protected tabs. I also have tried by using Google Chrome developer tools. Both of these couldn't help me out of this.

How i can make my style sheet take immediate effect on webpages.

https://www.ludhianaweddings.com/

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Webpage is looking styled on my browser chromium Version 60.0.3109.0 (Developer Build) (64-bit)

Comment: yeah it is styled...but changes are not being effected..

Comment: What do you mean by _but changes are not being effected._

Comment: like i changed background color of body and saved it...background didn't change...

Answer (score 0):

If you have Cloudflare SSL on I expect you probably also have their caching switched on?

Within the Cloudflare dashboard for your domain go to "Caching", the first option will be "Purge Cache". For best performance you can click "Purge Individual Files" and enter the URL of the CSS file you are updating. Alternatively click the dropdown and purge everything.

While you're working you may want to enable Development mode so you can frequently change files without having to purge the cache. This is also in the "Caching" tab, under "Development Mode".